# Projection from Earth

Tags: mathematics

If a Particle is projected from Equator due north with a velocity $v$ and Earth is rotating with a uniform angular velocity $\omega$.

How can it be shown that the highest latitude reached will be given by the following expression? \begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{2}-(\pi-2) \frac{\omega R}{v}
\end{equation}

Comment: Interesting formula - but where does it come from?

Comment: Why would it depend on $\omega$? From what height? $v$ is a speed, not a velocity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Astronomy (my be better suited to another Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 3):

No.

If v is greater than 11.2 km/s then the particle will escape.  But your model predicts that for arbitrary high velocity the highest latitude will approach pi/2

Moreover as v approaches zero, this model predicts a latitude of -infinity.